# how to duplicate automatically color from a cell in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Let's say in google sheet, I've got on column A different words with cells of different color.
I want that if a word from the column A appear somewhere between B1 to D10, the color of the cell turn automatically to the same color of the same word in column A.

Edit: Sorry I wasn't clear:the color of the cells in A are not fixed! So if I change the color on one word of a cell in column A, I want the color to change automatically in B1 to D10 for the same word.

Here an exemple:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZTwvmBSMkcCKOzL4sAmALFjDDN3KVp2pfZ1LrcQJtbI/edit?usp=sharing

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: if color in A is not fixed you need to solve this with script

Comment: So just to clarify, you want to change the background color of cells in ```A``` if you modify the background color of the same cell value in the range ```B1:D10``` right? Do you *also* want to modify the background color of cells containing the same value of a cell in ```A``` when the background color in ```A``` changes?

Answer (score 0):

custom formula for conditional formatting:

```
=B1=$A$1
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vJyAYqefLaPt3_HEJhEu8P_9VwkV2i3ExRlcyyY-WvY/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Thanks! It's good but I forgot a detail in my issue. Thanks anyway :)